# Multiple csv files plotted on same axis with different colors

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Consider the following csv files

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pylab as plt

csv1 = """x,y
0,1
1,0"""

csv2 = """x,y
0,0
1,1"""

csv3 = """x,y
.5,1
.5,0"""

csv4 = """x,y
0,.5
1,.5"""
```

I can plot them all on different axes

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
for i, csv in enumerate([csv1, csv2, csv3, csv4]):
    r, c = i // 2, i % 2
    pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv)).plot.scatter('x', 'y', ax=axes[r, c])

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

But how do I plot on same axis with different colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### a. Using matplotlib

matplotlib uses different colors automatically

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots()
for i, csv in enumerate([csv1, csv2, csv3, csv4]):
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv))
    axes.scatter(df.x, df.y)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### b. Using pandas

One would need to define a list of colors to use.

```
colors = ["blue", "orange", "green", "red"]
fig, axes = plt.subplots()
for i, csv in enumerate([csv1, csv2, csv3, csv4]):
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv)).plot.scatter('x', 'y', ax=axes, color=colors[i])

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you change `fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)` to `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`. Then make a list of colours that you wish to use and pass this to your plot using `color=colors[i]`:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pylab as plt

csv1 = """x,y
0,1
1,0"""

csv2 = """x,y
0,0
1,1"""

csv3 = """x,y
.5,1
.5,0"""

csv4 = """x,y
0,.5
1,.5"""

colors = ['red','green','blue','black']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, csv in enumerate([csv1, csv2, csv3, csv4]):
    r, c = i // 2, i % 2
    pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv)).plot.scatter('x', 'y', ax=ax, color=colors[i])
```

This results in the following graph:

[image]